# Do the systems always follow the same pattern?

Tags: game-dev-tycoon

I've been playing the lite version of Game Dev Tycoon and every playthrough I get the same message for the Master V. Can it ever do good in North America or does it always fail? I was hoping there would be some random factor to the consoles but it doesn't appear there is. Can someone clear this up for me? Do the consoles follow the same pattern no matter what or can they be random?

Answer (score 7):

Yes, all systems follow a timeline that roughly corresponds to the real life schedule of the various consoles and devices.

Below is the full timeline (at the base game speed - this gets stretched out or condensed depending on the game speed setting):

> **Y1 M1 W1** (Start of Game)
>
> - [Govodore G64](http://gamedevtycoon.wikia.com/wiki/Govodore_G64) made available.
> - [PC](http://gamedevtycoon.wikia.com/wiki/PC) made available.
>
> ---
>
> **Y2 M1 W2**
>
> - [TES](http://gamedevtycoon.wikia.com/wiki/TES) released.
>
> ---
>
> **Y3 M2 W3**
>
> - [Master V](http://gamedevtycoon.wikia.com/wiki/Master_V) released.
>
> **Y3 M9 W2**
>
> - [Gameling](http://gamedevtycoon.wikia.com/wiki/Gameling) released.
>
> ---
>
> **Y4 M2 W4**
>
> - [Vena Gear](http://gamedevtycoon.wikia.com/wiki/Vena_Gear) released.
>
> **Y4 M6 W2**
>
> - [Govodore G64](http://gamedevtycoon.wikia.com/wiki/Govodore_G64) discontinued.
>
> ---
>
> **Y5 M2 W4**
>
> - [Vena Oasis](http://gamedevtycoon.wikia.com/wiki/Vena_Oasis) released.
>
> **Y5 M12 W4**
>
> - [Super TES](http://gamedevtycoon.wikia.com/wiki/Super_TES) released.
>
> ---
>
> **Y6 M6 W2**
>
> - [TES](http://gamedevtycoon.wikia.com/wiki/TES) discontinued.
>
> ---
>
> **Y7 M7 W1**
>
> - [Playsystem](http://gamedevtycoon.wikia.com/wiki/Playsystem) released.
>
> ---
>
> **Y8 M4 W1**
>
> - [Vena Gear](http://gamedevtycoon.wikia.com/wiki/Vena_Gear) discontinued.
>
> ---
>
> **Y9 M2 W1**
>
> - [TES 64](http://gamedevtycoon.wikia.com/wiki/TES_64) released.
>
> **Y9 M8 W1**
>
> - [Super TES](http://gamedevtycoon.wikia.com/wiki/Super_TES) discontinued.
>
> ---
>
> **Y10 M8 W3**
>
> - [DreamVast](http://gamedevtycoon.wikia.com/wiki/DreamVast) released.
>
> **Y10 M11 W1**
>
> - [Vena Oasis](http://gamedevtycoon.wikia.com/wiki/Vena_Oasis) discontinued.
>
> ---
>
> **Y11 M3 W4**
>
> - [Master V](http://gamedevtycoon.wikia.com/wiki/Master_V) discontinued.
>
> **Y11 M5 W2**
>
> - [Playsystem 2](http://gamedevtycoon.wikia.com/wiki/Playsystem_2) released.
>
> **Y11 M12 W4**
>
> - [MBox](http://gamedevtycoon.wikia.com/wiki/MBox) released.
>
> ---
>
> **Y12 M11 W3**
>
> - [Playsystem](http://gamedevtycoon.wikia.com/wiki/Playsystem) discontinued.
>
> **Y12 M12 W1**
>
> - [Game Sphere](http://gamedevtycoon.wikia.com/wiki/Game_Sphere) released.
>
> ---
>
> **Y13 M8 W4**
>
> - [GS](http://gamedevtycoon.wikia.com/wiki/GS) released.
>
> ---
>
> **Y14 M1 W4**
>
> - [DreamVast](http://gamedevtycoon.wikia.com/wiki/DreamVast) discontinued.
>
> **Y14 M3 W4**
>
> - [PPS](http://gamedevtycoon.wikia.com/wiki/PPS) released.
>
> **Y14 M4 W2**
>
> - [Gameling](http://gamedevtycoon.wikia.com/wiki/Gameling) discontinued.
>
> ---
>
> **Y15 M2 W3**
>
> - [Game Sphere](http://gamedevtycoon.wikia.com/wiki/Game_Sphere) discontinued.
>
> ---
>
> **Y16 M5 W4**
>
> - [TES 64](http://gamedevtycoon.wikia.com/wiki/TES_64) discontinued.
>
> **Y16 M8 W4**
>
> - [MBox 360](http://gamedevtycoon.wikia.com/wiki/MBox_360) released.
>
> ---
>
> **Y17 M2 W3**
>
> - [MBox](http://gamedevtycoon.wikia.com/wiki/MBox) discontinued.
>
> **Y17 M4 W4**
>
> - [Nuu](http://gamedevtycoon.wikia.com/wiki/Nuu) released.
>
> **Y17 M12 W4**
>
> - [Playsystem 3](http://gamedevtycoon.wikia.com/wiki/Playsystem_3) released.
>
> ---
>
> **Y18 M6 W3**
>
> - [Playsystem 2](http://gamedevtycoon.wikia.com/wiki/Playsystem_2) discontinued.
>
> **Y18 M9 W1**
>
> - [GrPhone](http://gamedevtycoon.wikia.com/wiki/GrPhone) released.
>
> ---
>
> **Y20 M10 W4**
>
> - [MPad](http://gamedevtycoon.wikia.com/wiki/MPad) released.
> - [GrPad](http://gamedevtycoon.wikia.com/wiki/GrPad) released.
>
> **Y20 M12 W4**
>
> - [Wuu](http://gamedevtycoon.wikia.com/wiki/Wuu) released.
>
> ---
>
> **Y21 M6 W4**
>
> - [Nuu](http://gamedevtycoon.wikia.com/wiki/Nuu) discontinued.
>
> **Y21 M8 W4**
>
> - [MBox Next](http://gamedevtycoon.wikia.com/wiki/MBox_Next) released.
>
> ---
>
> **Y22 M2 W3**
>
> - [MBox 360](http://gamedevtycoon.wikia.com/wiki/MBox_360) discontinued.
>
> **Y22 M3 W3**
>
> - [Playsystem 4](http://gamedevtycoon.wikia.com/wiki/Playsystem_4) released.
>
> **Y22 M9 W3**
>
> - [Playsystem 3](http://gamedevtycoon.wikia.com/wiki/Playsystem_3) discontinued.
>
> ---
>
> **Y260 M12 W4** (End of Game)
>
> - [PC](http://gamedevtycoon.wikia.com/wiki/PC) no longer available.
> - [GS](http://gamedevtycoon.wikia.com/wiki/GS) no longer available.
> - [Wuu](http://gamedevtycoon.wikia.com/wiki/Wuu) no longer available.
> - [PPS](http://gamedevtycoon.wikia.com/wiki/PPS) no longer available.
> - [Playsystem 4](http://gamedevtycoon.wikia.com/wiki/Playsystem_4) no longer available.
> - [MPad](http://gamedevtycoon.wikia.com/wiki/MPad) no longer available.
> - [MBox Next](http://gamedevtycoon.wikia.com/wiki/MBox_Next) no longer available.
> - [GrPhone](http://gamedevtycoon.wikia.com/wiki/GrPhone) no longer available.
> - [GrPad](http://gamedevtycoon.wikia.com/wiki/GrPad) no longer available.

Data taken from the respective wikia pages.

Comment: Good job Compiling that list.

Comment: @SamyamA Oh, it's just the dates transcribed and sorted from the wikia. Not too much effort. Just figured the actual list would be a nice addition.

Comment: Y261 - nuclear apocalypse happens. People too busy living Fallout to be able to play it.

Answer (score 3):

Yes the consoles follow the same pattern everytime. Most of the consoles in game are influenced by real world consoles. They always follow the destiny of their real world counterparts. Even their timelines are influenced by their relative real world release times.

So console timelines and their success or failure are pretty much fixed.